# did not have extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini for send activation link to email

Tags: php, email, pdo

I have created login and register page using **php** with **pdo.**

After register, the activation link didn't send at registered email.

I refered this link [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost) in stackoverflow,

I don't have extension=php_openssl.dll in php. can anyone tell me, what i do?

I m using **xampp1.7.4**

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. did uncomment the  `extension=php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini` but still was having the issue.

On checking loaded extensions using the command `php -m` openssl was missing. At last i found that the directory for extensions was not properly set by default so had to un-comment `extension_dir = "ext"`

Hope this will help others

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the php_openssl.dll in you ext directory?
If you have that you should be able to get it working by adding the line to php.ini.

If you are missing the dll, you can try to download the same version of php as included in your XAMPP and get the dll file from there.
PHP downloads for windows can be found at http://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: Now i unstall my xampp, may i know the exact link to download xampp with i need feature above and all?

Comment: my xampp version is 1.7.4. so which version of php need to download from mentioned above link